# Minimum distance of a code given its basis

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, coding-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

I know that to determine the minimum distance of a code given its basis we can follow this procedure:

Let $\{ c_1, \ldots, c_k \}$ be a basis for a code of length $n$ and dimension $k$. Then the generator matrix is $B$ whose rows are $c_i$. I know that row ops on $B$ do not change the code so we can assume that $B = (P | I_k)$. Now the parity check matrix is given by $A = (P^\top | I_{n-k})$ and the minimum distance of the code is the minimum number of columns of $A$ that are linearly dependent.

The problem is that this approach can be very tedious for large codes as we have to reduce $B$ to echelon form, so my question are:

1) Is there in general an easier approach? Eg. looking at the weight of the codewords in the basis.

2) If $C$ is cyclic should I also follow the same approach?

Comment: 1) There is and its implemented in Magma. 2) For specific codes like BCH codes there are better methods due to the structure of the codes.

Comment: What is Magma??

Comment: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/

Comment: Computer algebra system.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/361046/61691 Note that "basis" and "generator matrix" are essentially the same.

Answer (score 3):

See the paper "The intractability of computing the minimum distance of a code" by Alexander Vardy in the *IEEE Transactions on Information Theory,* vol. 43, November 1997. Since this is behind a paywall, I quote the abstract below.

**Abstract:** It is shown that the problem of computing the minimum distance of a binary linear code is NP-hard, and the corresponding decision problem is NP-complete. This result constitutes a proof of the conjecture of Berlekamp, McEliece, and van Tilborg (1978). Extensions and applications of this result to other problems in coding theory are discussed.

Comment: Thanks for the exact quote. I am favoriting this question so that (hopefully) I can retrieve it the next time this question gets asked.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks. Seven years ago, you edited [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/361046/15941) whose answers also reference the Vardy paper.